# Is there an expression that depicts how people tend to spill their secrets during late night conversation?

Tags: research

This is for a research paper. I want to say that at night secrets emerge, revealing the real person. In the case I am writing about, it would be that there would be a certain energy that comes out at night.

Comment: If it's for a research paper, do you have any data backing up such assertion?

Comment: @Divizna That's not our concern.

Comment: "Pillow talk" for talk in bed afters sex. You can also mention the dim, intimate atmosphere of night as opposed to the bright public days.

Comment: You mean when people have been drinking, taking drugs, etc? Or some other situation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no word or standing phrase for that. But you can describe it as you did:

> Late at night, secrets emerge, revealing the real person. A certain energy comes out at night.

That's perfectly fine. You don't have to express every complex idea in one single word. In fact, it is better if you don't, because otherwise your writing will become too "dense" with meaning and too difficult to understand.